# Past 10 Week Performance or Past 10 Weeks Performance

Tags: grammatical-number

Simple question: I have this title "Past 10 Week Performance", and someone is telling me that it's supposed to be "Past 10 Weeks Performance". Which one is correct? My gut tells me it's the 1st one.

Comment: Anecdotally, your gut is wrong; I always see it as "...Weeks Performance". It is equivalent to saying "Performance over the past 10 _weeks_".

Comment: Actually, it's ***weeks'*** with an apostrophe. See the duplicate.